# express-jwt: unless condition is not being honored using mocha/chai

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

I am developing a site using the mean stack and express-jwt to block access to API calls to my site unless a user is authenticated.  There are certain API calls that I need users not logged in to access, i.e., `/api/login` and `/api/register`.  When I access the endpoints using firebug everything seems to work as expected, it blocks under the right conditions and allows under the right conditions.  I am even receiving the token under Firebug.

However, if I test using mocha/chai I am getting "401 unauthorized" error indicating "No authorization token was found".  I am using the following code to ignore selected endpoints:

app.js:

```
let expressJwt = require('express-jwt')

app.use(expressJwt({secret: process.env.AUTH_KEY}).
unless({path: ['/api/login', '/api/register', /^\/api\/external\/.*/]}));
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app, mongoose){
    app.use("/api/register", require("./routes/registration")(mongoose));
    app.use("/api/external/games", require("./routes/games")(mongoose));
    app.use("/api/external/shopping", require("./routes/shopping")(mongoose));
}
```

routes/registration.js:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function(){
    const express = require('express'); 
    const router = express.Router();
    const RegistrationFactory = require('../factories/RegistrationFactory');
    const registrationFactory = new RegistrationFactory();

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next();
    });

    /* GET users listing. */
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
        const registrationService = registrationFactory.create();
        registrationService.register(req.body, function(err, user){
            if (!err && user){
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(200);
            } else {
                return next(err);
            }
        })
    });

    return router;
}
```

I would like to block access to all of the routes except the three listed above.  What am I doing wrong?  I am a beginner to Node.js.